# EventInfo access modifiers

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, access-modifiers

I am stuck now at method to retrieve access modifiers of [EventInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object (reflected event field in C# .NET).

By access modifiers I mean: public/private/protected/internal and static, readonly etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory (at the IL level) there are basically three members making up the event:

- add
- remove
- raise

You can access each of those via a separate `EventInfo` property ([`AddMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.addmethod), [`RemoveMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.removemethod), [`RaiseMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.raisemethod)) and check the access modifier for each of them. For events declared in C#, I'd expect no raise method, and the add/remove methods to have the same accessibility.

Comment: That's clever. Every method of EventInfo should have same modificators, is it right?

Comment: @marty: Not necessarily. I could imagine public add/remove but private raise, for example. Not that the C# compiler uses raise at all. It would be odd to have public add but private remove - but I haven't checked to see whether that would be *invalid* in IL. (There's no way of representing it in C#, at least.)

Comment: You are right that C# does not allow declare add/remove method accessor with any modifier at all. It does not support declare custom accessor for raise method either. So, raise method is declared by default always?

Comment: @marty: No, the C# compiler doesn't provide it at all, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Ok, so I will scan add and remove. Thank for help, I appreciate that!

Comment: I would add: in general, when calling the `Get...` reflection methods (`Type.GetMethod`, `Type.GetField` etc.), and you're trying to get hold of a private member, you need to pass in the appropriate `BindingFlags` enum values (`BindingFlags.NonPublic`, and `BindingFlag.Static` or `BindingFlags.Instance` as appropriate). However, if **any** of the event's accessors are public, `GetEvent` considers the event to be public, and will retrieve the `EventInfo` even without passing in the `BindingFlags`.